# VHDL : process and counter does not work

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to program in vhdl  using the process statement. Below is my vhdl code

```
begin

dcm_clk PORT MAP(
    CLKIN1_IN => clk,
    RST_IN => reset,
    CLKOUT0_OUT => clk0_fast,
    CLKOUT1_OUT => clk0_dac,
    CLKOUT2_OUT => clk90_fast, --13.33MHz ; div =60
    CLKOUT3_OUT => clk_mux      --26.67MHz ; div =30 
);


process(clk_mux, reset)
begin
if (reset = '0') then
    if rising_edge(clk_mux) then
        if count_m = 0 then -- 0
            MUX_0 <= '1';
            count_m <= count_m + 1;
        elsif count_m = 29 then
            MUX_0 <= '0';
            count_m <= count_m + 1;
        elsif count_m = 57 then
            MUX_0 <= '1';
            count_m <= count_m + 1;
        elsif count_m = 86 then
            MUX_0 <= '0';
            count_m <= count_m + 1;
        elsif count_m = 115 then
            count_m <= (others => '0');         
    end if; -- end count_m
  end if; -- end clock

end if; -- end reset
```

The value of count_m seems to be stuck at the value '1'. I do not understand why there is no increment for the counter. Any help is much appreciated. The output from the testbench is shown below

[image: Testbench Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your unlabelled process is only incrementing count_m for four specific values of count_m, and count_m = 1 is not one of them.

Try:

```
UNLABELLED_PROCESS:
    process (clk_mux, reset)
    begin
        if (reset = '0') then
            if rising_edge(clk_mux) then
                count_m <= count_m + 1;
                if count_m = 0 then -- 0
                    MUX_0 <= '1';
                   --  count_m <= count_m + 1;
                elsif count_m = 29 then
                    MUX_0 <= '0';
                    count_m <= count_m + 1;
                elsif count_m = 57 then
                    MUX_0 <= '1';
                    -- count_m <= count_m + 1;
                elsif count_m = 86 then
                    MUX_0 <= '0';
                    -- count_m <= count_m + 1;
                elsif count_m = 115 then
                    count_m <= (others => '0');         
            end if; -- end count_m
          end if; -- end clock

        end if; -- end reset
    end process;
```

And what this does is increment count_m every clk_mux and when the value is 115 assigns it to all '0's.

And that gives something like:

[image: no_mcve_incrementing.png]

if I got your clock period arithmetic right.  Note that the assignment of count_m + 1 to count_m is overridden by the if statement for count_m = 115. You can also see that MUX_0 is a flip flop and it's output changes after the next clk_mux rising edge for a count_m value specifying a change.

Help for debugging should provide the answering reader the ability to recreate a specific error by supplying a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

In this case it was matter of a second process for clk_mux, four signal declarations with necessary initial values (missing any reset action) all in an entity and architecture pair:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity no_mcve is
end entity;

-- dcm_clk PORT MAP(
--     CLKIN1_IN => clk,
--     RST_IN => reset,
--     CLKOUT0_OUT => clk0_fast,
--     CLKOUT1_OUT => clk0_dac,
--     CLKOUT2_OUT => clk90_fast, --13.33MHz ; div =60
--     CLKOUT3_OUT => clk_mux      --26.67MHz ; div =30
-- );

architecture foo of no_mcve is
    signal count_m: unsigned (9 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal clk_mux: std_logic := '0'; -- clock
    signal mux_0:   std_logic := '0';
    signal reset:   std_logic := '0';
begin

UNLABELLED_PROCESS:
    process (clk_mux, reset)
    begin
        if (reset = '0') then
            if rising_edge(clk_mux) then
                count_m <= count_m + 1;
                if count_m = 0 then -- 0
                    MUX_0 <= '1';
                   --  count_m <= count_m + 1;
                elsif count_m = 29 then
                    MUX_0 <= '0';
                    count_m <= count_m + 1;
                elsif count_m = 57 then
                    MUX_0 <= '1';
                    -- count_m <= count_m + 1;
                elsif count_m = 86 then
                    MUX_0 <= '0';
                    -- count_m <= count_m + 1;
                elsif count_m = 115 then
                    count_m <= (others => '0');         
            end if; -- end count_m
          end if; -- end clock

        end if; -- end reset
    end process;
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 19.25 ns;
        clk_mux <= not clk_mux;
        if now > 7.3 us then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: Hi . Thanks for your response. I can get the code working.  I failed to see this earlier, as the solution was so simple.Also,I will make sure that i post a working code in the future.